# Does Keras allow using independant classifier

Tags: keras, text-classification

I have spam data set classified into 0:ham or 1:spam. I created the Embedding layer with Keras and then I used Conv1D following with other layers. My question is about adding a classifier like Random Forest or SVM or anything else using Scikit-learn library after the Conv1D layer, so that the output of Conv1D can become as input to Random forest? for example:

```
model.add(Conv1D(filters=100,kernal_size=2,activation="relu")
model.add(RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0))
...
model.compile
model.fit
```

I know the second line gives syntax error but I tried to explain my idea. Thank you.

Comment: to my best knowledge this is not possible

Comment: Layer is just a tensor operation, not a model. What you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to classify data without using neural network I want only to use the convolution layer to extract features then use another classifier for my scientific research purposes. Should I implement convolution layer from scratch?

Comment: This answer solved my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55903763/6688772